# ElasticSearch query on json data

Tags: python, elasticsearch, jupyter-notebook, elasticsearch-5

I have json data in format

{"issue_number": 1, "created_at": "2016-03-13", "closed_at": "2016-04-13", "labels": ["Category: Bug", "Latitude:41.925573", "Longitude:-87.649249", "OriginationPhase:Requirements"], "State": "closed"}

I need to write an elastic search query that retrieves all locations that got atleast 3 issues created for same location i.e latitude and longitude.

To my understanding i need to retrieve the data where issues are more than 3 for same location. So i need to groupby latitude and longitude , and count should be greater than or equal to 3

I dont have much understanding on elastic search. i have referred couple of sites and tried the below code.

```
    q = {
    'aggregations':{
                'labels':{
                    'nested':{
                            'path':'labels'
                },
                'aggs':{
                    'latitude':{
                        'terms':{
                                'field':'labels.Latitude',
                                'min_doc_count':3
                            },
                        'aggs':{
                            'by_top_hits':{
                                'top_hits':{
                                    'size':3
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
              }

         }
    }
}
```

But i didn't get the expected result and query doc_count is 0.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a query. In this case, you can start with a [Match All Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-all-query.html) so that all the documents get evaluated.

Regarding you agg query, I don't see the need for the nesting, you can try something like:

```
GET yourindex/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "aggs": {
    "locations": {
      "terms": {
        "field":"latitudeNameField"
      }
    }
  },
  "_source": "false"
}
```

Comment: what exactly is "latitudeNameField" reffering to here?